# Uso eclipse y no me reconoce "Integer.parseInt.showInputDialog" ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: java

No me reconoce el codigo `"Integer.parseInt.showInputDialog"` y pienso que está podríais decirme si es fallo del programa o mío?
public class Ejercicio4tema2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int edad; 
        boolean permisoPaterno= true;
        boolean permisoConducir= true;

        edad = Integer.parseInt.showInputDialog(null, "¿Qué edad tienes?"));

        boolean esMenor = edad>=16 && edad<18;
        boolean menorPuedeConducir = esMenor && permisoPaterno && permisoConducir;
        boolean menorNoPuedeConducir = esMenor && ! permisoPaterno;
        boolean puedeConducir = edad>=18 && edad<=75 && permisoConducir;
        boolean noPuedeConducir = edad>75 || edad>=18 && edad<=75 && ! permisoConducir;

        System.out.println("Es Menor y puede conducir = "+ menorPuedeConducir);
        System.out.println("Es Menor y no puede conducir = "+ menorNoPuedeConducir);
        System.out.println("Es Mayor y puede conducir = "+ puedeConducir);
        System.out.println("Es Mayor y no puede conducir = "+ noPuedeConducir);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> **No** me **reconoce** el codigo `"Integer.parseInt.showInputDialog"`

**`parseInt()`** es un método estático perteneciente a la clase **`Integer`**, que admite o recibe como argumento un `String` - `Integer.parseInt("Mi cadena");`

Por otro lado **`showInputDialog()`** es un método estático perteneciente a la clase **`JOptionPane`**, que recibe como parámetro un argumento de tipo **`Object message`** y nos devuelve un **String**, que es lo que recibe el anterior método `parseInt()` -  **`JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qué edad tienes?");`**

---

**Tu línea quedaría así:**

`edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qué edad tienes?"));`

Answer (score 0):

Ahora cuando pongo edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qué edad tienes?")); me salta un error de "JOptionPane cannot be resolved".
Cómo podría resolverlo?

Comment: Antes del comienzo de la clase, tendrás que importar su correspondiente paquete.. `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` También decirte que te / nos borrarán esto, ya que deberías haber comentado, en vez de haber creado una respuesta. Ya me comentas donde tu pregunta si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, mil gracias por la ayuda. Y no sabía que me borrarán el comentario, fallo mío lo siento.

Comment: También si crees que te he ayudado podrías dar por contestada tu pregunta en el respectivo check. ;)